# kubectl keeps getting error when trying to list pods

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

After running this :

```
aws eks update-kubeconfig --region eu-west-1  --name my-cluster
```

I tried to run `kubectl get pods` but I keep getting this error :

```
E1229 13:04:42.538976   82870 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
E1229 13:04:42.873405   82870 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
E1229 13:04:43.208848   82870 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
E1229 13:04:43.561855   82870 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
E1229 13:04:43.896372   82870 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)
```

Mentioning here that aws is well configured and works fine.

Comment: Do you have correct permissions in your aws-auth configmap for your cluster. If not, you should configure it correctly. You should ask the owner of the IAM user who created the cluster to run this command;

`kubectl get cm aws-auth -o yaml -n kube-system`

If your IAM user credentials that is located in your local environment doesn't have correct permissions to make API request, you can't do it.